# Sencha touch 2 Can't read json from .net server

Tags: .net, json, sencha-touch-2

I have a store that read json string from .Net Server.
The problem is that the sencha app wrtire that their is no result ("emptyText").
This store worked good with dummy data (data:[ ]) but when I try to read proxy I'm having a problem

The store code:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'widget.myStore',
    autoLoad: true,  
    config: {
        model: 'myApp.model.myModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'scripttag', //Also tried ajax and jsonp
            url: 'http://localhost:XXXX/ServerResponse/ReponseT.aspx?CityID=1',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
```

The Server Code (C#):

```
 List<result> Li = new List<result>();
                    result LR = new result()
                    {
                        id = 1,
                        Title = "Heu There"                                                     
                    };
                    Li.Add(LR);
 string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Li, Formatting.Indented);    
 Response.Write(ans);
```

I have a warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "URL"

Thats it... I hope some one will be able to say what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the header type. This below code works for me to fetch JSON data from .Net server.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: reqUrl,
            defaultHeaders : 'application/json',
            headers: {
               "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,

            success : function(response, opt) {
                benefitsRespObj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                // your code goes here
            }
 });
```